# Wordpress Database Error And Theme Functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I had this error recently and i can't resolve it.

```
Table 'k9d9p7u7_wrdp1.wp_4_datalist' doesn't exist
```

Component

```
Core
```

CallStack

```
wp-content/themes/eduma/functions.php
wp-content/themes/eduma/functions.php:60
```

Query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `wp_4_datalist`
WHERE `url` = "/"
```

Comment: Did you check to see if that table actually does exist?

Comment: yes i did, and yeah it does exist

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to elaborate your problem more.
Now, based on what you have mentioned. I can tell you that find the wp-config.php in root folder and check for these lines
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */

```
define('DB_NAME', 'yourdatabase');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'databaseuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'datbaseuserpassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

After checking the right configuration of above 4 lines, make sure that your user has all the privileges to make any changes in the database.

Also ensure that your mysql server is working fine.

As far as functions.php is concerned, you need to debug. For this

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Find this line in wp-config.php and change the false to true i.e.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks, i edit the Question for more clarification, and i'm gonna try this way.

Comment: This error appears only in one site of the multisite network, not even the main one.

Comment: On the debug and then try to solve the problem. Can't tell you without checking files

Comment: If it's multisite then you can take help from the websites which are working